# How to make an activity keeps loading until database is updated before proceeding to next activity?

Tags: android

This is the situation now. I have 2 apps which share the same MySQL database. One is for the user and the other one is for myself. After the user submitted a request, the user's app has to keep loading until I press "Accept" from my app which will update a column in the database before the user can proceed to the next activity.

Below is the code on user's app. Here's how I do it currently but it is not efficient and not the right solution. I set a timer for it which means I need to quickly update the database within that period.

```
final Runnable onUi = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this will run on the main UI thread
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SearchRockets.this,RocketFound.class);

                SearchRockets.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SearchRockets.this.finish();
            }
        };

        Runnable background = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This is the delay
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // This will run on a background thread
                //Simulating a long running task
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Going to Profile Data");
                uiHandler.post(onUi);
            }
        };

        new Thread(background).start();
```

How do I make it in real-time that the user's app keeps loading until I update the column and then the user is allowed to the next activity ? I'm using PHP for for Android to interact with the database.

Comment: check [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Take a look at [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for running tasks in the background. But it sounds like you are just looking for a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) to display to the user while they wait for the server to respond.

Comment: Use push notification functionality..

Comment: Although an AsynkTask can resolve your issues, Are you saying that the unless you approve the user is going to see the ProgressBar all along. Thats a bad UX design. Have you considered the scenario where you are in a remote location and unavailable to approve for days at a time. Ideally you should redirect the user to a pending for approval screen, and push notify the user app when you have approved the request, so that the navigation is unlocked.

Comment: You update user app's database after web request, right? When got the http response, update the database, and then send some broadcast.

Comment: I want to display the ProgressBar to user until the server responds and bring user to the next activity.

Comment: @SOFT1234 than as i said `AsyncTask` is the one you are searching for. On `preExecute()` you show `ProgressBar`. On `doInBackground()` you do your work and on `postExecute()` function you move to `RocketFound Activity`. There exist a lot of examples on how to use `AsyncTask` here in `SO`, just google it